# The Wait Operation Timeout Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website (MVC 4 Project), which [link](http://www.windowsadair.com) is.

Sometimes, especially, about 20-25 people entered my website together on same time, my website is not open and error I have like picture below. I have this error only min 20 people entered my website same time, together.

[image]

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to figure out the right connectionstring on server.

Comment: I dont understand what do you tell me. My connection string is Password=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXXDb;Data Source=XXX    How can I figure out connectionstring.